# sem --wait does not wait after a while loop that reads from a file

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm trying use GNU parallel in bash to run several instances of a program in parallel, with different arguments in each instance. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to read these arguments from a file, and have the script wait until all parallelized jobs are done. GNU parallel's `parallel --semaphore`, aka `sem`, seemed to be an easy way to do this.

#### MCVE

Using a modified version of the [basic example](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html#UNDERSTANDING-A-SEMAPHORE) from the `sem` docs, I created a minimal test-case to illustrate my issue:

```sh
while read i; do
    echo -n "$i "
    sem -j 4 "sleep $i && echo $i finished"
done < args.txt
echo
echo 'Started wait'
sem --wait
echo 'Done waiting'
```

Here, `args.txt` is a file that simply contains:

```
1
2
3
4
```

#### Expected vs. actual output

I expected to see an output that looks something like:

```
user@host:~$ ./test-sem.sh
1 2 3 4 
Started wait
1 finished
2 finished
3 finished
4 finished
Done waiting
```

However, surprisingly, `sem --wait` does not actually wait for the tasks to get done, and instead, I get an output like this:

```
user@host:~$ ./test-sem.sh
1 2 3 4 
Started wait
Done waiting
user@host:~$ 1 finished
2 finished
3 finished
4 finished
```

That is to say, the script executes and terminates, and the `sem` jobs then run and print their respective outputs in the background! Why is this happening? How can I get `sem --wait` to actually wait after initializing all `sem` jobs inside the while loop?

Interestingly, it's *reading from the file* that's causing the problem, not the while loop itself. That is to say, the following works as expected:

```sh
i=1;
while (( $i <= 4 )); do
    echo -n "$i "
    sem -j 4 "sleep $i && echo $i finished"
    let i=i+1
done
echo
echo 'Started wait'
sem --wait
echo 'Done waiting'
```

But my actual use-case has a file with more complex argument combinations, so I'd really like to read the arguments from the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [gnu parallel docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-xargs--n1.-Argument-appending):

> --semaphore
>
> - [...]
> - --semaphore implies --semaphorename `tty` unless --semaphorename is
>   specified.
>
> --semaphorename name
> --id name
>
> Use name as the name of the semaphore. Default is the name of the controlling tty (output from tty).
>
> The default normally works as expected when used interactively, but when used in a script name should be set. $$ or my_task_name are often a good value.
>
> The semaphore is stored in ~/.parallel/semaphores/

You have to use the same name for the semaphore to be the same! The following code:

```
while read i; do
    tty
done < somefile
tty
```

outputs:

```
not a tty
/dev/pts/0
```

All `tty` does it calls `ttyname` on **stdin**. Because stdin comes from file, it's no longer the same. You can:

- pass name manually with `--id <some unique name>`
- use a different file descriptor `while read -u 3 ...; do ..; done 3<file`.

Comment: I see! So `sem` uses `tty` by default for the semaphore name (so that all sem commands run in a given terminal are linked to each other, I guess). But when I _read from a file_, the tty changes since it's tied to standard input: this happens even outside of a script, i.e., on the terminal, as opposed to what the docs suggest. Wish the `sem` manpage documented this issue better - seems like it should be a fairly common use-case! Using `sem --id test <program>` along with `sem --wait --id test` works, thank you!